# How efficient is std::uniform_int_distribution ? Can it even hog (exhaust) my entropy pool?

Tags: c++, random

So, is `std::uniform_int_distribution` allowed to call some "`get_new_random_bits_from_source()`" in a loop, possibly 10 or 100 or infinite times, until the random number fits into the range?

What if the "`get_new_random_bits_from_source`" uses /dev/random? I.e. it consumes the entropy pool, which is a precious and finite resource? Can it even exhaust?

So, what cost can I expect for  `std::uniform_int_distribution`?  In terms of consumed time, consumed "pseudorandom capacity" (it has a finite period, then numbers start repeat), and consumed entropy (from the entropy pool). Is any upper cost limit?

Comment: What is `get_new_random_bits_from_source`? `uniform_int_distribution` is a distribution. It shouldn't consume _anything_ from the entropy pool. If you use the `std::random_device` generator, **that** will do that though.

Comment: the exact implementation isn't specified but in general it shouldn't request more bits from the generator than is required to represent the required range of outputs

Comment: @AlanBirtles Oh, in that case, I was wrong. Oups ... Does that mean that even if one uses a PRNG (not `std::random_device`) it can consume bits from the entropy pool? If that's the case, it sounds really bad.

Comment: You don't need to worry about running our of entropy,  The entropy of the universe increases every moment.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `random_device` isn't guaranteed to be cryptographically secure. It just happens to be on at least one implementation. That said it should still be a non-deterministic PRNG even if it isn't a CSPRNG.

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, I know that, but what would surprise me is if `uniform_int_distribution` used the entropy pool when a PRNG is used (which doesn't even touch the pool). If one actually use `std::random_device` as a generator, then sure, the **generator** will use the pool.

Comment: @NathanOliver Ok. that one made me chuckle. Needed that this morning.

Comment: @TedLyngmo fair, I was nitpicking. And FWIW even libstdc++ uses `/dev/urandom` if available, and `rand_s` or `rdseed` if not... but it will fall back to MT19937 if all other options aren't available at compile time.

Comment: `random_device` should be used to seed a pseudo-RNG; it should not be used directly with a distribution.

Comment: The standard doesn't specify too much. But you can look at your specific compiler/library and find out. For instance on VS 2022, there is no extra state info in `std::uniform_int_distribution` beyond upper and lower limits. So, at a minimum, it's going to pull a full size value from the random generator source on each call. Very inefficient for small ranges like 0 to 7.

Answer (score 3):

> So, is std::uniform_int_distribution allowed to call some "get_new_random_bits_from_source()" in a loop, possibly 10 or 100 or infinite times, until the random number fits into the range?

The standard says:

> > amortized constant number of invocations of g

g is uniform random bit generator. 10 and 100 invocations would satisfy that requirement; inifinite arguably does not.

> So, what cost can I epxect for std::uniform_int_distribution?

You can measure or analyse the implementation to find out. There are no costs specified in the standard.

---

For what it's worth, there is an excerpt from one standard library implementation (libstdc++). I've removed some underscores to improve readability:

```
    if (urngrange > urange)
      {
        if (detail::_Power_of_2(urngrange + 1)
            && detail::_Power_of_2(urange + 1))
          {
            while (f != t)
              {
                ret = uctype(urng()) - urngmin;
                *f++ = (ret & urange) + param.a();
              }
          }
        else
          {
            // downscaling
            const uctype uerange = urange + 1; // urange can be zero
            const uctype scaling = urngrange / uerange;
            const uctype past = uerange * scaling;
            while (f != t)
              {
                do
                  ret = uctype(urng()) - urngmin;
                while (ret >= past);
                *f++ = ret / scaling + param.a();
              }
          }
      }
    else if (urngrange < urange)
      {
        // upscaling
        /*
          Note that every value in [0, urange]
          can be written uniquely as
          (urngrange + 1) * high + low
          where
          high in [0, urange / (urngrange + 1)]
          and
          low in [0, urngrange].
        */
        uctype tmp; // wraparound control
        while (f != t)
          {
            do
              {
                constexpr uctype uerngrange = urngrange + 1;
                tmp = (uerngrange * operator()
                         (urng, param_type(0, urange / uerngrange)));
                ret = tmp + (uctype(urng()) - urngmin);
              }
            while (ret > urange || ret < tmp);
            *f++ = ret;
          }
      }
    else
      while (f != t)
        *f++ = uctype(urng()) - urngmin + param.a();
  }
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution/operator() does say it'll make a constant number of calls to the generator so I don't think it is unrestricted?

Comment: @AlanBirtles: It doesn't say "constant"; it says "amortized constant". That word's important.

Comment: @AlanBirtles Fair enough. I've updated the answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas its a fairly small difference in context, it means that it might for example use 2 calls to the generator one time, then 1 the next giving an average of 1.5, still way less than infinite